# How to generate a graph from this linear interpolation function

Tags: algorithms, programming

I'm writing a computer program that has some animations that are calculated with linear interpolation

So the function in question is

$x_1 = x_0 + (1 - x_0) \cdot c \cdot dt$

Where $dt$ is the time for this frame in seconds and $c$ is some constant. This functions will cause $x$ to tend toward $1$, but really it could be any value.

The point is to tweak $c$ in this algorithm so that $x \approx 1$ within some set duration.

The goal would be to have some function $f(T) = c$ where $T$ is the desired duration of this algorithm.

How would you go about solving this?

Comment: Why not simply solve for $c$ in your equation?